# vue-loader ignores the <template> tag on .vue files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, gulp

I am trying to use webpack, vue-loader and gulp to compile single component files, but the damn thing completely ignores the `<template>` tags and as result I am getting warnings such as: "Component is missing template or render function".

It works if I use the `template` property, though.

Any ideas ?

The `package.json`:

```js
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Adinan Cenci",
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.2.47"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
        "webpack": "^5.69.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack-stream": "^7.0.0"
    }
}
```

App.vue:

```js
<script>
module.exports = {
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello world!!!'
        }
    },
    template: `if I use the template property, then it works`
}
</script>

<template>
   <div>but this template tag will be ignored</div>
</template>
```

main.js:

```js
const Vue     = require('vue');
const App     = require('./App.vue');

//----------------------------------------

const app = Vue.createApp(App);

//----------------------------------------

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
{
    app.mount('#app');
});
```

the gulp.js file:

```js
const gulp                = require('gulp');
const rename              = require('gulp-rename');
const webpack             = require('webpack');
const webpackStream       = require('webpack-stream');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

async function build() 
{
    return gulp.src('./src/main.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream({
        mode: 'development', 
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: true,
                __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: true
            })
        ]
    }))
    .pipe(rename('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
}

exports.build = build;
exports.default = gulp.series(build);
```

Comment: "vue-template-compiler" - at least this. You're using mismatched versions

Comment: Thank you @EstusFlask, but how so ? Those are the most recent versions for both.
... actually I am using vue 3, I don't think I even need vue-template-compiler..

Comment: There's `@vue/compiler-sfc` for V3.

Comment: @EstusFlask it is present in the node_modules folder.
Yesterday I also noticed that webpack freaks out when faced with the `<style>` tag.

` node:events:491  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[PluginError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| > .test { background: red | }] {`

Comment: Ok, adding vue-css-loader seems to have fixed the <style> tag not working, still no idea why the template is being ignored.

Comment: And if I add the setup property to the <script> tag ... none of them work...
there was a time when I used to like this framework quite a lot when it was simple to use

Comment: Webpack isn't really a thing that is simple to use, apart from Vue, most real-world setups may look simple but have a bunch of pitfalls. You can still use it in a simple way by ignoring .vue sfc feature that is a made-up thing. Or you can stick to the recommended Webpack/Rollup setups with Vue CLI and Vite respectively. Btw it's either `<template>` or `template:` and not both, the latter requires to use vue runtime compiler.

Comment: I know @EstusFlask, I am saying that `<template>` does not work at all.
I really don't want to use vue cli nor vite. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this bi**h working.

[Here is the template](https://gist.github.com/adinan-cenci/aaecc684ad11dcb8ce2b12d6e7972eb2) if anyone is interested.

Not even sure what did it, guess it were the damned imports.

Thank you for your time [@estus-flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask)